# js form submit not working when trying to execute two functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create two actions from one submit but it looks like my form submit is not working.  It seems function2() takes over before function1() is able to complete:

double.php

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
     <script>
       alert('here we go');
     </script>
   </body>   
<html>
```

double1.php

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>

       function function1(){ 
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "1 changed!";     
        document.getElementById("theForm").action ='http://example.com/testbed/public/double.php';            
        document.getElementById('theForm').submit();        
       }
       function function2(){         
         document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "2 changed!";
         window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");
       }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="" id="theForm">   
          <input type="button" onclick="function1();function2();" />
      </form>
      <div id='1'></div>
      <div id='2'><div>
   </body>
<html>
```

Comment: you should use addEventListener

Comment: for what event?

Comment: The two functions are doing contradictory things -- one submits the form to one address, the other redirects the window location to a different address.  What are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon that is a coding style nitpick; it is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: adding the event listener doesn't make any sense to me.  I want to execute a php script that I don't have control over and I want to redirect the url to a new page like www.google.com or www.stackoverflow

Comment: You can't simultaneously send the page to two separate addresses. You could execute the PHP script via ajax and then redirect to your other page after the ajax call resolves.

Comment: how would I do that if I don't have control of the first php script

Comment: By submitting the form as an ajax call instead of as a direct form submit.  Same thing as far as the PHP script is concerned, so long as you send the same form params.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're going to have cross-origin problems, then, aren't you. Hmm, never mind, bad suggestion, sorry....

Comment: But what @DanielBeck suggests is the only way you can do both. If the remote api isn't CORS enabled you need a server side  proxy to do this

Comment: DanielBeck charlietfl  thank you that helps put me on the right track